# LdapRepository configuration no match

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-ldap

We're trying to set up an LdapRepository from Spring Ldap and struggling with retrieving a user list. The Ldap server is an ActiveDirectory.

We can log in via `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` using the same credentials.

Spring Properties:

```
spring.ldap.base=cn=Users,dc=company,dc=local
spring.ldap.password=secret
spring.ldap.username=useradmin
spring.ldap.urls=ldap://172.16.36.60:389
```

When reading out the `inetOrgPerson` retrieved from logging in, it says:
    dn="CN=useradmin,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=local"

So I think the base is correct.

No, when trying to `.findAll()` from the repository, nothing is found. Our model class currently looks like this.

```
@Entry(base="cn=Users,dc=company,dc=local",objectClasses = {"inetOrgPerson","top"})
public final class CompanyUser implements Serializable {

@Id private Name dn;
@Attribute(name="username") private String userName;
@Attribute(name="mail") private String email;
...
}
```

When leaving out the `base` on `@Entry` annotation, the repository will return count=0. With the `base` attribute on the annotation, query throws:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100241, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
'CN=Users,DC=company,DC=local'
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not adding base on the entity class is correct, if base is already fully defined in the properties.

The reason the server returned no results, could be fixed by removing "inetOrgPerson" object class from the `@Entry`, for now.